# Creating a anonymous block to display 1 to 5 and getting the below error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp interval date binary national character
   nchar
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "=" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Here is the code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
clear scr;
DECLARE v_counter := 0;
BEGIN
LOOP
v_counter:= v_counter+1;
IF v_counter=3 THEN CONTINUE; END IF;
EXIT WHEN v_counter=5;
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_counter='||v_counter);
END;
```

Comment: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
clear scr;
DECLARE
v_counter := 0;
BEGIN
LOOP
v_counter:= v_counter+1;
IF v_counter=3
THEN 
CONTINUE;
END IF;
EXIT WHEN v_counter=5;
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_counter='||v_counter);
END;

Comment: You need to declare a type for `v_counter` e.g. `NUMBER`: `DECLARE v_counter NUMBER := 0;` I think that is the only error.

Comment: Also, since the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` is outside the loop, it will display only the final value for `v_counter`.

Comment: You have unnecessarily complicated the code. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Creating a anonymous block to display 1 to 5 and getting the below error

Your code will never display 1 to 5. As @David said in the comments -

1. You haven't declared the `data type` for the `variable`.
2. The `DBMS_OUTPUT` is outside the `LOOP`, thus it will print only the last value held by the variable.
3. That `IF-ELSE` construct seems unnecessary if you just want to print 1 to 5.

You could achieve the same in just one `FOR LOOP` -

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> BEGIN
  2    FOR i IN 1..5
  3    LOOP
  4      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_counter='||i);
  5    END LOOP;
  6  END;
  7  /
v_counter=1
v_counter=2
v_counter=3
v_counter=4
v_counter=5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The same could be done in `SQL` -

```
SQL> select 'v_counter ='||level counter from dual connect by level <=5;

COUNTER
---------------------------------------------------
v_counter =1
v_counter =2
v_counter =3
v_counter =4
v_counter =5

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is  the line reading

```
DECLARE v_counter := 0;
```

You forgot to specify the variable's datatype.

It should read

```
DECLARE v_counter number := 0;
```

Of course, instead of `number` you might choose `pls_integer` if you're more confortable with it.